# Error "More than one matching bindings are available" when using Ninject.Web.Mvc 2.0 and ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Recently I've switched to Ninject 2.0 release and started getting the following error:

```
Error occured: Error activating SomeController
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
  1) Request for SomeController

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for SomeController only once.
```

However, I'm unable to find certain reproduction path. Sometimes it occurs, sometimes it does not.
I'm using `NinjectHttpApplication` for automatic controllers injection. Controllers are defined in separate assembly:

```
public class App : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        INinjectModule[] modules = new INinjectModule[] {
            new MiscModule(),
            new ProvidersModule(),
            new RepositoryModule(),
            new ServiceModule()
        };

        return new StandardKernel(modules);
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        RegisterAllControllersIn("Sample.Mvc");
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
    }

    /* ............. */

}
```

Maybe someone is familiar with this error.

Any advice?

Comment: FYI, it isn't exclusive to ASP.NET MVC 1.0. I just had it happen in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 as well.

Comment: I created a repro project for this situation and uploaded it to the Ninject-dev group. Hopefully someone will recognize the issue. I wasn't able to see an easy fix. http://groups.google.com/group/ninject-dev/files

Comment: FYI, I have verified that this is fixed for me in version 2.1.0.0 of  NinjectNinject.Web.Mvc (MVC2). In the latest version you no longer need to call RegisterAllControllersIn(...).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I finally figured this issue out recently.  Apparently, the NinjectHttpApplication.RegisterAllControllersIn() function doesn't do all of the proper bindings needed.  It binds your concrete controller implementations to IController requests.  For example, if you have a controller class called SampleMvcController, which inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller.  It would do the following named binding during application start:

```
kernel.Bind<IController>().To(SampleMvcController).InTransientScope().Named("SampleMvc");
```

But when debugging the NinjectControllerFactory, I find that request are being made for the Ninject Kernel to return an object for the class "SampleMvcController", not for a concrete implementation of IController, using the named binding of "SampleMvc".

Because of this, when the first web request that involves the SampleMvcController is made, it creates a binding of SampleMvcController to itself.  This is not thread safe though.  So if you have several web requests being made at once, the bindings can potentially happen more than once, and now you are left with this error for having multiple bindings for the SampleMvcController.

You can verify this by quickly refreshing an MVC URL, right after causing your web application to restart.

The fix:

The simplest way to fix this issue is to create a new NinjectModule for your controller bindings, and to load this module during application start.  Within this module, you self bind each of your defined controllers, like so:

```
class ControllerModule : StandardModule {
      public override Load() {
        Bind<SampleMvcController>().ToSelf();
        Bind<AnotherMvcController>().ToSelf();
      }
    }
```

But if you don't mind changing the Ninject source code, you can modify the RegisterAllControllersIn() function to self bind each controller it comes across.

Comment: Thanx for the hint. I'll try it and mark your answer. Have you notified Nate Kohari already? =)

Comment: Thanks for this, we were pulling our hair out with this issue.

Answer (score 16):

I have been dealing with this problem for months. I tried so many options but was unable to come to a solution. I knew that it was a threading problem because it would only occur when there was a heavy load on my site. Just recently a bug was reported and fixed in the ninject source code that solves this problem.

Here is a reference to the [issue](http://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/closed#issue/17). It was fixed in build 2.1.0.70 of the Ninject source. The key change was in [KernelBase.cs](http://github.com/ninject/ninject/commit/126b824a93d834a788f36b34bcc77fbc1751cd2d#diff-0) by removing the line

```
context.Plan = planner.GetPlan(service);
```

and replacing it with

```
lock (planner)
{
    context.Plan = planner.GetPlan(service);
}
```

To use this new build with MVC you will need to get the latest build of [Ninject](http://github.com/ninject/ninject) then get the latest build of [ninject.web.mvc](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc). Build ninject.web.mvc with the new Ninject build.

I have been using this new build for about a week with a heavy load and no problems. That is the longest it has gone without a problem so I would consider this to be a solution.

Comment: Awesome!  This is big news.  Been dealing with it myself.  Thanks for providing this answer, Steve!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you really are creating a single completely new `Kernel` from scratch in your `OnApplicationStarted` every time it's invoked ? If you're not and you're actually creating it once but potentially running the registration bit twice. Remember that you're not guaranteed to only ever have one `App` class instantiated ever within a given AppDomain.

Comment: Take a look at README in the bottom of the page http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc (I think that my code is pretty similar). However, when I look to NinjectHttpApplication Application_Start() method http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc1/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectHttpApplication.cs it makes me think that configuration is done per single kernel instance.

Comment: @Cray: I will look in time - sorry dont have time now but wanted to answer in case it unblocked you. The main point of my post is to say "this exception suggests that you put a duplicate set or Bindings into the kernel somehow, perhaps by initialising twice into the same kernel", no matter where you got the code and regardless of whether your question represents an accurate reflection of your actual code that is failing. (I have done zero with the RTM NI2 but lots with various pre-2 builds)

Answer (score 2):

My answer was a bit more obvious.

I had declared the binding for one of my controllers more than once during refactor of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my global.ascx.cs file:

```
        public void RegisterAllControllersInFix(Assembly assembly)
    {
        RegisterAllControllersInFix(assembly, GetControllerName);
    }

    public void RegisterAllControllersInFix(Assembly assembly, Func<Type, string> namingConvention)
    {
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(IsController))
            Kernel.Bind(type).ToSelf();
    }

    private static bool IsController(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsPublic && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsInterface;
    }

    private static string GetControllerName(Type type)
    {
        string name = type.Name.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (name.EndsWith("controller"))
            name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("controller"));

        return name;
    }
```

Then called it from my OnApplicationStarted() method as follows:

```
        RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        RegisterAllControllersInFix(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Difficult to know whether this fixed it though because it's so intermittent.

Comment: Try something like WebClient.DownloadString("http://yoursite/") in loop,... in several threads =)