# Error activating HttpContext - More than one matching binding is available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC app with a simple NinjectModule:

```
public class MainModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<AppSettings>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<HttpContext>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current); // <-- problem
        Bind<MainDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind<UserInfo>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

This is the only binding code in my entire app. When I run my app, I immediately get this runtime error:

> Error activating HttpContext
>   More than one matching bindings are available.
>   Activation path:
>    3) Injection of dependency HttpContext into parameter httpContext of constructor of type UserInfo
>    2) Injection of dependency UserInfo into parameter userInfo of constructor of type HomeController
>    1) Request for HomeController
>
> Suggestions:
>    1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for HttpContext only once.

The error message seems to be saying that I've defined the `HttpContext` binding more than once, but the only binding statements in the entire application are in `MainModule`, and I've clearly only defined one binding for `HttpContext`. If I comment out that line of code, I stop getting the error, but the `HttpContext` that gets injected is not correct (it's an empty, newly instantiated `HttpContext` rather than `HttpContext.Current`).

The error message does describe the exact injection sequence I would expect to occur...

`HttpContext` should get injected into the constructor of `UserInfo`, which looks like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public UserInfo(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    // ... etc ... //
}
```

And `UserInfo` should get injected into the constructor of `HomeController`, which looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private readonly UserInfo _userInfo;

    public HomeController(AppSettings appSettings, UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        _userInfo = userInfo;
        ViewData[Token.AppSettings] = _appSettings;
        ViewData[Token.UserInfo] = _userInfo;
    }

    // ... actions here ... //
}
```

Why does this result in an error? This seems like a very straightforward dependency injection scenario. In what way am I defining the binding for `HttpContext` more than once?

Comment: You've shown us the main module. You havent told us if you're using Ninject.Web.MVC3 and/or where your Kernel is getting created. The error strongly suggests you're executing the module loads into a single Kernel more than once, e.g. by triggering it in you `Global` / `HttpApplication` construction/start (of which there are almost always >1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the Ninject.MVC3 extension than you have to remove

```
Bind<HttpContext>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current); // <-- problem
```

because the HttpContext binding is already added by the extension.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Ninject.MVC3 nuget package, and you're right, eliminating that binding fixes the problem. I originally thought I was getting a blank `HttpContext` when I removed the binding, but that turned out to be caused by something else. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

May want to review this one quickly and see if it is similar to your issue: [Error "More than one matching bindings are available" when using Ninject.Web.Mvc 2.0 and ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423862/error-more-than-one-matching-bindings-are-available-when-using-ninject-web-mvc)